# Like - Sharer.php ignoring image despite og meta

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, addthis

Despite the meta tags (the first one I never used before, but it came up in the addthis forums);

And the debug tool getting the data in a correct manner:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mondiales.nl%2F

The  facebook sharer code does not use the image specified. No images show up at all, there is no thumbnail chooser.

Looking at the HTML of the facebook sharer page, the image is actually there! The thumbnail chooser has a display:none. And when posting the damn thing, no image shows up on the wall.

Stop using addthis and implement a like function using the just the Facebook API? But from what I read, Facebook does a request for the page to get it's data so the JS part should not be the issue, should it?

Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a restriction on the width/height ratio of images shared, the ratio must be less than 3.0

Your image is too wide (211/66 = 3.19) - add some vertical whitespace and it'll share OK i think

For future reference this is mentioned on both the old [Share Button docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) and the [Open Graph protocol docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) (under 'og:image')

Comment: That fixes things! Where did you get this info?

Comment: It's listed a few places in the docs, for example the 'og:image' reference on the main [Open Graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), but probably not in enough places now that I think about it - i've created a task for myself to document it more clearly.
I've also updated my answer above to make it clearer for anyone else that finds this question

Answer (score 1):

I've found that once I've posted something to my wall from the sharer or the app, if I try to repost it, it will remember the original image (or no image in your case).

It might be worth clearing the whole cache/cookies from your browser and see if that does the trick.

If not, you'll find that if you log in as another user of Facebook and they try to post it, it will pick up on the new image on their account and not yours.

I'm not exactly sure how Facebook caches the images.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old but this may help someone else with the same issue. FB caches shared urls along with the thumb images and descriptions. To update the cache, add a bogus parameter to your shared query string, like, "?v=1". This gets the latest og tags.